# Byte Stuffing on MSP430

Tags: escaping, uart, msp430, dma

I'm trying to send to my computer some data that should be parsed. Since I need to separate this data, I would like to use the byte stuffing.
I'm using the DMA module to tranfer data from a buffer(6byte + STARTbyte) to the UART my problem is that I should define the size of the block to send (DMASZ)and inizializate the buffer at the beginning but this size could be different in reference to the message to send. 
Anyone has any suggestion to do that?

the message to send should be

START DATA1  DATA2  DATA3  DATA4  DATA5  DATA6

and in the wrost case defining an ESC byte and if the message is composed only from value ugual to the ESC byte

START ESC ESC ESC ESC... tot 4x6 byte+ START byte

I would appreciate so much.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? When you have the data in the buffer, you know how much bytes you have.

Comment: the problem is that the data are samples of a sensor, so they change continuously and when one or more sample has the value of the start flag, the number of bytes in the buffer change and that causes some problems to initializate the buffer and size of block to transfer

Comment: And why is that a problem? After you've added the escape bytes, you know how many bytes you have.

Comment: so I should every time that I add an Escape byte initiallizate the buffer and update the DMAxSZ ?

Comment: *After* you've handled all escaped in the buffer.